# Sinon async test: array is not filled in before push happens

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, asynchronous, sinon

I write test for AngularJS application in Sinon & Chai. I do `$httpbackend` request and I have a fake array of users - `backendUsersResponse`. It's available in my .spec.js but it's not filled in yet when I call the function `openSettings` and so my users are an empty array in my controller.

How & where can I tell my code to wait till array is filled in? How do you test async javascript stuff like this?

Thanks in advance!

Controller code:

```
export default class UserAccountsController {
    constructor(UserModel, userSettingsDialog) {

      this.UserModel = UserModel;
      this.userSettingsDialog = userSettingsDialog;

      this.users = [];

      UserModel.query()
          .then((users) => {
              this.users = users;
          });

    }

    openSettings(user) {

       const userToUpdate = user || new this.UserModel();

       this.userSettingsDialog.openDialog(userToUpdate)
           .then((data) => {
               const cmd = data.value;

               if (cmd === 'saveSettings') {
                   const isNew = angular.isUndefined(userToUpdate.id);
                   userToUpdate.$save();
                   if (isNew) {
                      this.users.push(userToUpdate);
                   }
               }
           });
      }

  }
UserAccountsController.$inject = [ 'UserModel', 'userSettingsDialog'];
```

Test

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon/pkg/sinon';

describe('userAccounts Controller', () => {
   'use strict';

   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myproject'));

   let $httpBackend = null;
   let $q = null;
   let UserModel = null;
   let userSettingsDialog = null;

   beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _UserModel_, _$q_) {
       $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
       UserModel = _UserModel_;
       $q = _$q_;
   }));

   describe('openSettings', () => {
      let $controller;
      let backendUsersResponse;

      beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
          userSettingsDialog = {
              openDialog: sinon.stub(),
          };

          $controller = _$controller_;

          backendUsersResponse = {
              users: [
                  {
                      id: 1,
                      name: 'John',
                      role: 'admin',
                  },
                  {
                      id: 2,
                      name: 'Diego',
                      role: 'editor',
                  },
              ],
          };
      }));

      it('should check if new user is pushed to an array', () => {
        // arrange
        const ctrl = $controller('UserAccountsController', {
            userSettingsDialog: userSettingsDialog,
        });

        const user = new UserModel({
            name: 'Lander',
        });
        const data = {
            value: 'saveSettings',
        };

        $httpBackend.expectGET('api/users').respond(200,      backendUsersResponse);

        userSettingsDialog.openDialog.withArgs(user).returns($q.resolve(data));

        $httpBackend.expectPOST('api/users').respond(200, user);

        // act
        ctrl.openSettings(user);

        $httpBackend.flush();

        // assert
        expect(userSettingsDialog.openDialog).to.have.been.called;
        expect(user.name).to.equal('Lander');
        expect(ctrl.users).not.to.be.empty;
        expect(ctrl.users.length).to.be(3); //<-- this one fails, array length is always 2, user is not added

      });
   });
});
```